# Apex stub from an xml with attributes

Tags: apex, callout, soap, xml, wsdl2apex

I have created apex stub classes from a wsdl and invoked a external SOAP webservice from it. The response is an xml with attribute in elements. I need to extract the value (which is 'PPPPPP' when wd:type="Item_ID" in below xml

```
<wd:Sales_Item_Reference>
     <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d89472a929901c34895bc41a6259610</wd:ID>
     <wd:ID wd:type="Item_ID">PPPPPP</wd:ID>
</wd:Sales_Item_Reference>
```

These are the corresponding stub class methods generated

```
//for Sales_Item_Reference
public class Sales_ItemObjectType {
        public SOAPStub.Sales_ItemObjectIDType[] ID;
        private transient String[] ID_type_info = new String[]{'ID',s_ns0,'Sales_ItemObjectIDType','0','-1','false'};
        public String Descriptor;
        public String[] Descriptor_att_info = new String[]{'Descriptor'};
        private transient String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{s_ns0,'true','false'};
        private transient String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'ID'};
}

//For ID
public class Sales_ItemObjectIDType {
        public String input;
        private transient String[] input_type_info = new String[]{'input','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','1','1','false'};
        public String type_x;
        public String[] type_x_att_info = new String[]{'type'};
        private transient String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{s_ns0,'true','false'};
        private transient String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
}
```

Sales_ItemObjectIDType.type_x gives me the attribute value 'Item_ID' but how do I retrieve the value 'PPPPPP'

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example response of:

```
<wd:Sales_Item_Reference>
     <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d89472a929901c34895bc41a6259610</wd:ID>
     <wd:ID wd:type="Item_ID">PPPPPP</wd:ID>
</wd:Sales_Item_Reference>
```

I'd expect to access the Element value of `PPPPPP` via `Sales_ItemObjectIDType.input`. This isn't the elements attribute, but rather its value.

Something like this:

```
Sales_ItemObjectType calloutResponse = // the result from some callout
for(Sales_ItemObjectIDType objectType : calloutResponse.ID) {
    if(objectType.type_x == 'Item_ID') {
        System.debug('Item_ID is ' + objectType.input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I tried that already and I get a null value. When I do the same callout using postman, I get values back. So, null is not right

Comment: Can you provide the `CALLOUT_RESPONSE` from the debug log? It would appear that the XML SOAP response isn't being deserialized in the Apex objects correctly.